# Two events fire the same function

Tags: javascript

This anonymous function is fired by mouse movement.

```
var timeout;

// onkeypress

document.onmousemove = function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){alert("move your mouse");}, 1000);
}
```

Can I get it to be fired on key press as well? Or is the only way to do this efficiently defining the function as a named function and calling it like this:

```
document.onmousemove.namedfunction();
document.onkeypress.namedfunction();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w7c95/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it almost the same way you're doing it right now:

```
var timeout;

document.onmousemove = document.onkeypress = function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){alert("move your mouse");}, 1000);
}
```

However, reusing the same function multiple times is probably justification for giving it a name and just referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave it anonymous...

```
document.onmousemove = document.onmousemove = function(){
```

But, I wouldn't.